# Get parent <li> item with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, treeview

I am trying to get the parent `<li>` when I click on a specific `<li>` item.

http://jsfiddle.net/doonot/GjbZk/

So let's say I click on `submodule 1`, I get the clicked ID with `$(this).attr('id');`
How can I now get the ID of the parent `<li>` which is in this case `module 1`?

Please note that my tree is quite big, so it has to be flexible.

Thanks a lot, much appreciate your answer.

Comment: It's a Java based application, and I am using JSP to build the website!

Comment: @dooonot - But this question is not related to Java in any way, hence the question and subsequent removal of the "Java" tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var parentModule = $('this')             //the selector of your span
    .parents('li:eq(1)')                 //get the next li parent, not the direct li
    .children('.rightclickarea:first')   //get the first element, which would be the span
    .attr('id')                          //get the span id
```

Answer (score 29):

You can use the [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the first ancestor that matches a selector:

```
var li = $(this).closest("li");
```

From the jQuery docs:

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the
>   current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Comment: and if the click handler was bound to the the span in the lowest li, it will just get it's parent's li. or if bound to the lowest li, it gets itself

Comment: Shoud this work? `var id = $(this).closest("li").attr('id'); `

Comment: @dooonot - Yes, assuming the closest `li` element has an `id`.

Comment: I just see that it is not the `li` element that stores the `id`, it is the `span` element which is surrounded by the `li` element. What do I have to do to get this `id`?

Answer (score 6):

```
var parent = $(this).closest("li");
```

Comment: I am not able to get this working. It always says `undefined`. Please see my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doonot/GjbZk/).